# Fill complex 3d shapes with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to reproduce a picture so I can modify some aspects of it. This is the picture:

[image]

How can I fill between 3d shapes in order to form the shell?

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning, patterns, intersections}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{5}{55}{0}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw[black, name path = A] (0,1,0) -- (3,3,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, start angle=90, end angle=-150, radius=3] coordinate(C1) -- (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \draw[black, name path = B](3,3,0) -- (5,3,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5, radius=3, start angle=90, end angle=-150] coordinate(C3)-- (C1) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, start angle=-150, end angle=90, radius=3] -- cycle;
    \draw[red](3,3.1,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, radius=3.1, start angle=90, end angle=-150] coordinate (C2);
    \draw[black, name path = C](3,3.1,0) -- (5,3.1,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5, radius=3.1, start angle=90, end angle=-150] coordinate(C4) -- (C2) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, start angle=-150, end angle=90, radius=3.1] -- cycle;
    \draw[black,name path = D] (C1) --(C2);
    \draw[black, name path =E] (3,3,0) -- (3,3.1,0);
    \draw[black, name path= F] (5,3,0) -- (5,3.1,0);
    \draw[black, name path = G] (C3) -- (C4);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With output:

[image]

Comment: First, you need to draw a tangent between the outer curves on the bottom.  Fill closed paths corresponding to sides (as seen), working from back to front.

Comment: Start with InkScape, draw the outline and fills and as much as you can. Then after you import the code to TikZ you can take care of the additional details.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimers**:

1. Ti*k*Z has no real 3D engine, so you need to do a lot of things yourself.
2. The following code works specifically for your view angles. It is, in principle. possible to make it work for more/all view angles, but this is considerably more effort.
3. I followed the path implicitly outlined by your choice to load the pfplots library fillbetween. In principle, you may compute the relevant intersection points and draw the relevant paths by hand, but it is true that it is somewhat more convenient to use that library here.

Having said all these things, here is the code.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing,
positioning, patterns, intersections,shadings}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{00}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{5}{55}{0}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw[black, name path = A] (0,1,0) -- (3,3,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, start angle=90, end angle=-150, radius=3] coordinate(C1) -- (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \draw[black, name path = B](3,3,0) coordinate (C5) -- (5,3,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5,
radius=3, start angle=90, end angle=-150] coordinate(C3)
coordinate[pos=0.75] (t1) -- (C1) arc[canvas is yz
plane at x=3, start angle=-150, end angle=90, radius=3] 
coordinate[pos=0.25] (t2) coordinate (C6)-- cycle;
    % the following arc may not be necessary
    \draw[black](3,3.1,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, radius=3.1, start
angle=90, end angle=-150] coordinate (C2);
    \draw[name path = C](3,3.1,0) -- (5,3.1,0) 
    arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5, radius=3.1, start angle=90, end angle=-150]
    coordinate(C4) coordinate[pos=0.75] (b1) -- (C2) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=3, start angle=-150, end
    angle=90, radius=3.1] coordinate[pos=0.25] (b2) -- cycle;
    \path[name path=I] (t2) -- (t1);
    \shade[bottom color=gray,top color=black,
        intersection segments={of=B and I,sequence={L1--R0--L0}}];  
    \draw[name path=H] (b2) -- (b1);
    \shade[bottom color=black,top color=gray,intersection segments={of=C and
    H,sequence={L2--R0}}];
    \fill[gray!60]  (C1) --(C2) -- (C4) -- (C3) -- cycle;
    \draw[name path = D] (C1) --(C2);
    \draw[name path = G] (C4) -- (C3);
    \fill[gray!20!black]  (3,3,0) -- (3,3.1,0) -- (5,3.1,0) -- (5,3,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[black, name path=E] (3,3,0) -- (3,3.1,0);
    \draw[black, name path=F] (5,3,0) -- (5,3.1,0);
    % G and F
    \fill[gray!60] (5,3.1,0) arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5,radius=3.1,
    start angle=90, end angle=-150] -- (C4) -- (C3)
    arc[canvas is yz plane at x=5, radius=3.0, start angle=-150, 
    end angle=90] -- (5,3,0) ;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Could one draw the full shape shown in the screen shot? In principle yes, but the effort will be really huge.